# 2D array issues in Google Scripts / Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I have some code that retrieves the data from a Google sheet. I then loop through this data for dates that equal today's date only. I want to then put those values into another sheet. I'm probably not understanding how exactly 2D arrays work... below is what I have so far. I know my loop to find only today's entries is working. Not sure what I'm doing wrong though. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The n variable returns the correct number of rows that SHOULD be in the array. However, the row and column count are not correct. The sheet I'm reading data FROM has 4 columns. I only need 3 of them though.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Edit Info');
var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
var values = rows.getValues();

Logger.log(values.length)
Logger.log(values[0].length)

var todayValues = [];
var todValues = "";
var rowValues = [];

var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) {
dd = '0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
mm = '0'+mm
}  

today = mm + "/" + dd + "/" + yyyy;
Logger.log("Today: " + today)
var n = 1;
for(var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {   
var formattedDate = values[i][0];
var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(formattedDate), "GMT-6", 
"MM/dd/yyyy");
//Logger.log("NewDate: "+newDate)
if(newDate == today){

  //todValues += values[j][0] + "," + values[i][3] + "," + values[i][2];
  todayValues.push(values[i][0], values[i][3], values[i][2]);
  n = n + 1
  Logger.log(values[i][0] + ", " + values[i][3] + ", " + values[i][2])
}
}

Logger.log("N Row Count: " + n) //How many times the date was actually 
found
Logger.log("Rows: " + todayValues.length)
Logger.log ("Columns: " + todayValues[0].length)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you used the Debug option in the script editor.  See the [Troubleshooting page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting) for use if you have not. It is easier than using the logs.

When you do this you should find that your retrieved data saved to values is different than the data saved to todayValues.  Simplified, it will be something like this:

```
values  [["A", "B", "C"],["D", "E", "F"]]
todayValues  ["A", "B", "C","D", "E", "F"]
```

Note the additional square brackets in values.

You want the code in your loop to read

```
 todayValues.push([values[i][0], values[i][3], values[i][2]]);
```

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. It made my code to populate another sheet work as well. :)